# 'accerelate&decelerate scroll' like tiny tower (near lobby) in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, touch, cocos2d-x

How would I implement the accerelate/decerelating effect when scrolling as you would see near lobby in tiny tower game?

Would it be a scrollview under the hood?

-edit-
Would it be a more interesting question if it needs to be done in cocos2d-x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/21/cocos2d-and-uiscrollview/

I used the above tutorial to successfully implement scrollview like UI with cocos2d-x.